# How to add Unique Key for a column in a model in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, indexing, entity-framework-6

I am trying to make a column as Unique key in my model.

my code is :

```
public class Customer
{
    [Index("abcd",IsUnique = true)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

and I am using following references:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Still i am getting

```
Error   103 The type or namespace name 'IndexAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Am i missing anything?
Iam using EF 6.1 version

Thanks in advance

Comment: Already using the refrence

Comment: But do you have that line at the top of your code file?

Comment: Yes,now changed to top of the code file.Still doesn't work

Comment: Tried your code with EF 6.1.1 - works.

Answer (score 4):

Rephrase my answer.  (apologies if shortened URL's are now allowed)

In .net 4.5 the Index attribute only exists in the file (EntityFramework.dll)

The Dll [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema(v=vs.110).aspx) does not contain the Index attribute

The [EntityFramework.dll version 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema(v=vs.113).aspx) or later contains this attribute

Browse to the file EntityFramework.dll and add a reference the error will vanish and the code will compile.

The namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema is also part of this EntityFramework.dll

I assume its a blunder by Microsoft and may be corrected in .net 5

Comment: Thanks, that does not make sense to put index attribute in entity framework i had to install ef to my model project.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click Project **Reference** section
2. Then Click **Add Reference** in that popup left menu select **Assemblies**
3. Check `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` dll
4. Import following namespaces in code

   `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`
5. [Install Entity Framework for this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1133988/Installing-the-Entity-Framework-for-the-Project-in)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you've got EntityFramework referenced in the project that your model class is in - I moved the model classes out of my MVC website into a separate DLL but I assumed that because IndexAttribute is in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema namespace that it was in the System.ComponentMode.DataAnnotations assembly - it's actually in the EntityFramework assembly, so you need the reference.

Thanks to Animuson for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
Just install the Entity Framework in each project you need to use IndexAttribute.

---

**Step-by-step instructions:**

- Open Package Manager Console
- Copy-paste this: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0 -ProjectName MyProject`
- substitute "MyProject" with your project and press enter

More infos: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/